# How do I add a class to a react element when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this react component and I am trying to create a hamburger menu but, I don't know how to add a class when a button is clicked. I am new to React so please go easy on me. When I run the below code it doesn't work and throws an error in the Chrome dev tools.

```
function Nav() {
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
const navUL = document.getElementById('navul');
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  navUL.classList.toggle('show');
});
  return (
<header>

  <h2>
    <a href="/">
      Travis Helms
    </a>
  </h2>
  <nav>
    <ul className="flex-row" id='navul'>
      <li className="mx-2">
        <a href="#about">
          About me
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Portfolio</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Contact</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Resume</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button className="hamburger" id="hamburger">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars}></FontAwesomeIcon>
    </button>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: You're using React so I suggest you [go back and learn the basic principles](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). You shouldn't be using native JS DOM methods to update the DOM. You should be using state to inform _how_ the DOM is updated and let React do it's thing. Ignore what @about14sheep said. And you shouldn't be using jQuery either.

Comment: I have been reading a lot on how to do this and I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone please help? This is my first React assignment. I am still learning the basics and I am trying to get this assignment done over the weekend.

Comment: @smasherCoder You'll want to review a couple concepts. First, how to store/update state (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), since React needs to keep track of whether it should add a class or not. Then, review how to attach event handlers to React Components (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), since you'll need to update that state variable on click. With that information in hand, you can then conditionally set the className of the element based on the state variable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I went to a tutor and worked with them to come up with this solution to toggle my hamburger menu. Just thought I would add this answer for the benefit of other beginning React programmers.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function Nav(props) {
const [navClass, setnavClass]= useState("flex-row");
const [toggledNav, settoggledNav]= useState(true);

const addClass=() => {
  if (toggledNav){
    setnavClass("flex-row show");
    settoggledNav(false);
  }else {
    setnavClass("flex-row");
    settoggledNav(true);
  }

}

  return (
<header>

  <h2>
    <a href="/">
      Travis Helms
    </a>
  </h2>
  <nav>
    <ul className={navClass} id='navul'>
      <li className="mx-2">
        <a href="#about">
          About me
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Portfolio</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span onClick={() => props.setmenuSelect(1)}>Contact</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Resume</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button onClick={addClass} className="hamburger" id="hamburger">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars}></FontAwesomeIcon>
    </button>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to React! It's an amazing framework!

It would have been more helpful if you provided the error you are getting but from the code you shared I can see there are a few things you need to do differently.

Generally, you can use event listeners in React for certain things, and there is a certain way to add them properly, but for the most part they are not used very frequently. Instead, for example, to assign a click event to an element in React, all you need to do is pass it the `onClick` attribute with the function you want it to execute when it is clicked, for example `<button onClick={doSomething}>click me</button>`.

An easy way to control the state of your component is by using the `useState` hook and toggle the class of an element using state. In your case, it could look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Nav = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <header>
            <h2>
                <a href="/">Travis Helms</a>
            </h2>
            <nav>
                <ul className={"flex-row " + (isOpen ? "show" : "")}>
                    <li className="mx-2">
                        <a href="#about">About me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Portfolio</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Contact</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Resume</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button
                className="hamburger"
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
            >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars}></FontAwesomeIcon>
            </button>
        </header>
    );
};
```

It looks like you are in a very early stage of learning React and for you to be successful coding with React you need to cover a few basics like state management, props, children and a few more things. I would recommend going on YouTube and find a good introduction video to React and code along to it! There are a lot of great resources in there for people who are just starting with React, just make sure it's something fairly recent (I'd say 2020 onwards).